# select tag sits one pixel lower in Firefox than it does in Chrome

Tags: css, html

```css
#allday {
    width: 180px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 2px !important;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-image: initial;
    white-space: pre;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    cursor: default;
}
```

I inspected the element in both browsers but I'm not really seeing where the discrepancy is. Has anyone been through this before with the select tag?

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EksT4/) I see no difference. You need to provide us with more code to help you. What version of FF and Chrome?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jthVU/. FF 17.0. Chrome is whatever the very latest release for Win8 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to see a fiddle or an example this is a wild guess, but I've had some issues before with different browsers showing different heights/padding/margins and adding `display:block` has sometimes helped... but not all of the time.

Comment: I added the display: block; however that is not the answer in this case. I'm also noticing that there is a black border showing in FireFox but not in Chrome.

Comment: @sepoto I notice you have ` border: 1px solid;` with no colour specified. This would cause this to default to black. Do you need the border? This could be causing the issue.

Comment: Either way the select is still 1px too low. Could this have to do with the height of the br difference in Google Chrome vs. FireFox?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't see the gap, I think that may be due to me looking at this through Chrome and Firefox on a mac, I will look at this on a pc in the morning and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

```
            #allday {
            width: 180px;
            height: 20px;

            margin-right: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            -webkit-appearance: menulist;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-align: center;
            border-image: initial;
            white-space: pre;
            -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
            color: black;
            background-color: white;
            cursor: default;
            display: block;
        }
```

I also had to add a 0px bottom margin to the label above the select however the br was not modified. Thanks for all your help!